# how do I fix this error to be able to use bootrun

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies, bootrun

This is the main error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The full one is

```
> Task :bootRun
14:16:03.478 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@1e43efcc

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2021-11-08 14:16:03.949  INFO 34468 --- [  restartedMain] .JavaWebDevTechjobsPersistentApplication : Starting JavaWebDevTechjobsPersistentApplication on DESKTOP-EKB1MD1 with PID 34468 (C:\Users\amy\IdeaPro\assign4\build\classes\java\main started by amy in C:\Users\amy\IdeaPro\assign4)
2021-11-08 14:16:03.949  INFO 34468 --- [  restartedMain] .JavaWebDevTechjobsPersistentApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-08 14:16:04.000  INFO 34468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\amy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/amy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/amy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/amy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/amy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/amy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/amy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2021-11-08 14:16:04.000  INFO 34468 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-11-08 14:16:04.000  INFO 34468 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-11-08 14:16:04.506  WARN 34468 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2021-11-08 14:16:04.521  INFO 34468 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-08 14:16:04.521 ERROR 34468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:597) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:805) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:801) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:771) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.launchcode.techjobs.persistent.JavaWebDevTechjobsPersistentApplication.main(JavaWebDevTechjobsPersistentApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:686) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:994) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:335) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted


Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

This is my code for *build.gradle*

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.launchcode'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {

    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.5.6'
    
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.6'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.6'

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.5.6'

    testImplementation("org.jmockit:jmockit:1.49")

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.6'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.5.6'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.6'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.5.6'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.5.6'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.5'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.5.6'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.6') {

        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'

    }

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'


}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${classpath.find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }.absolutePath}"
}
```

Here is my code for *.run*

```
    <component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="assign4 [bootRun]" type="GradleRunConfiguration" factoryName="Gradle">
    <ExternalSystemSettings>
      <option name="executionName" />
      <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
      <option name="externalSystemIdString" value="GRADLE" />
      <option name="scriptParameters" value="bootRun" />
      <option name="taskDescriptions">
        <list />
      </option>
      <option name="taskNames">
        <list />
      </option>
      <option name="vmOptions" />
    </ExternalSystemSettings>
    <ExternalSystemDebugServerProcess>true</ExternalSystemDebugServerProcess>
    <ExternalSystemReattachDebugProcess>true</ExternalSystemReattachDebugProcess>
    <DebugAllEnabled>false</DebugAllEnabled>
    <method v="2" />
  </configuration>
</component>
```

How do I fix the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist` do I add another dependency????

I am using *Gradle*

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced exactly the same error when I upgraded my project to `spring-boot-x-2.6.4`.

In my case upgrading `org.springframework.boot` and `io.spring.dependency-management` plugins resolved the problem.

Judging by your *build.gradle*, this might also help in your case. One of your [Spring plugins has version '2.2.2.RELEASE' from end of December 2019](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.2.2.RELEASE), while your [Spring dependencies are from October 2021](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.5.6).